# Centering MKMapView on an annotation

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

Although the process for doing this is well documented, I am unable to solve this problem.

All I want to do is to take the coordinate at which I have just created an annotation and have the map zoom in and center on it. I followed this tutorial with some modifications:
http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/

The MapViewAnnotation class consists of just a title and the coordinates.
_detailItem is simply an object that holds a name, latitude, and longitude as strings.

I have a basic map. I'm using a storyboard (so, ARC). I have coordinates. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];

    // Set some coordinates for our position
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    double thisLat = [_detailItem.EventLat doubleValue];
    double thisLong = [_detailItem.EventLong doubleValue];

    location.latitude = (double)thisLat;
    location.longitude = (double)thisLong;

    // Add the annotation to our map view
    MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:_detailItem.EventName andCoordinate:location];
    [self.map addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
}

// When a map annotation point is added, zoom to it
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1000, 1000);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}
```

Yeah. When I do this, the annotations shows up as expected, but the map doesn't center on it or zoom in. During debug, I found that didAddAnnotationViews isn't being called at all! Yet, I've clearly made an explicit call to addAnnotation.

Help?

Comment: did you set your view controller to be the map's delegate?

Comment: I assume you're selecting it so that you can see the callout? Then make sure to write a `viewForAnnotation` that enables the callout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `didAddAnnotationViews` isn't being called at all

In your `viewDidLoad` implementation, add this line:

```
self.map.delegate = self;
```

See if that changes things.

Comment: Or if he added the map in IB, just set the delegate in IB on the connections inspector tab.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Yeah, the delegate seemed to be the issue, as Rob and Benny mentioned.

Comment: Another problem... `didAddAnnotationViews` is called and the map zooms into the user's location, not the annotation. I turned the show user location property off, and now it won't zoom in or center at all, despite the call to `didAddAnnotationViews`